# Calling a method with a Dictionary argument

Tags: c#

I have a method starting with this line

```
public string CustomerInfo(Dictionary<string, object> arglist)
```

I am trying to call it with this code

```
string testval = CustomerInfo(Dictionary< string, object>);
```

The error is

> Dictionary is a type but used as a variable.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: if you had a method `string TranslateNumber(int num){}` would you call it `var resul = TranslateNumber(int);`?? That is what you are doing here, you are not passing a dictionary instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it this way

```
  string testval = CustomerInfo(new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

C# 6  Dictionary Initializers

```
  string testval = CustomerInfo(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
        { "1",1 } , {"2",2 }, {"3",new object() }
      });
```

Or pass a dictionary object

```
  var arglist = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    { "1",1 } , {"2",2 }, {"3",new object() }
  };
  string testval = CustomerInfo(arglist);
```

Comment: This worked for me - Many thanks for taking the time to answer this question !!

Answer (score 2):

There's an issue in your code. The dictionary being passed is not initialized

you should try

```
String testval = CustomerInfo(new Dictionary< string, object>());
```

or

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary< string, object>();
string testval = CustomerInfo(dictionary);
```